# Paypal buy it now button not doing anything

Tags: html, asp.net, paypal

Im sure this is obvious but I can't seem to get the auto-generated paypal code to work with my site. I see no debug errors. The button just does nothing when it is clicked. Any help would be appreciated

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<div class="background_subpages"> 
<div id="shirtsBG" class="RoundBorder">
    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="xxxx@gmail.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Green">
        <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
        <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
        <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
        <table>
        <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Sizes">Sizes</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
            <option value="Small">Small $11.99 USD</option>
            <option value="Medium">Medium $11.99 USD</option>
            <option value="Large">Large $11.99 USD</option>
        </select> </td></tr>
        </table>
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
        <input type="hidden" name="option_select0" value="Small">
        <input type="hidden" name="option_amount0" value="11.99">
        <input type="hidden" name="option_select1" value="Medium">
        <input type="hidden" name="option_amount1" value="11.99">
        <input type="hidden" name="option_select2" value="Large">
        <input type="hidden" name="option_amount2" value="11.99">
        <input type="hidden" name="option_index" value="0">
        <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
        <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
        </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because I was using a form within a form. This code in my page load did the trick

```
if (!IsPostBack)
        { }
        else { }
        Form.Action = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
        Form.Method = "post";
```